# Cannot install Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-installation, 16.04

I'm running a desktop with 256GB SSD, Samsung SyncMaster 943nw, USB mouse and 4 OS (Windows 7 and 10, opensuse and Ubuntu 15.10).

Now I tried to install 16.04 after downloading and creating a bootable DVD. In the past I installed every new release of Ubuntu since 13.04 without problems. With 16.04 I am not successful at all. When I'm booting from DVD, the very first screen appears with light magenta and at the lower rim an icon keyboard and man. After a while the screen goes black and the steady light at the screen starts blinking, just as if the computer is shut off. The DVD works on for a few minutes and then - nothing - no input possible, not even ctrl-alt-delete or similar.

I tried to install Kubuntu and Xubuntu, same result. After that I tried to upgrade via software center. The upgrade succeeded, but the first boot showed just a single line of fschk output and resulted in a black screen with blinking light.

It seems to me, that there is something wrong with the driver for the monitor.

Have you any idea what I can try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)